# Usage of articles when the noun is specifically described

Tags: articles, definite-articles

In the sentence

> We are [a/the] team of six developers working on financial software projects from the USA, Canada, and Australia.

where the word *team* is described specifically enough so there is only this  team that corresponds to this description, am I allowed to use 'the' before the word *team* since it actually refers to the specific team? Or is the only correct article here 'a'?

Comment: Probably. Let's hear the whole sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin sure, I updated the question

Comment: Are you introducing the team to people who don’t know about any team or are you talking to people who know about a team but don’t know that you are it?

Comment: @Jim first, they don't know that such team exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the **listener *does not have* any prior knowledge about the team**, then the **article "a" is appropriate**. The word "team" is not described specifically enough as other teams with 6 developers working on financial software projects may exist in the world.

If the **listener *does have* some prior knowledge about the team** (e.g. he already knew that some team was working on the financial software projects, he just didn't know which team exactly), then the **article "the" is appropriate**.

**Practical examples:**

- On a **"About us" website** page about a financial software team, you would use **"a team"**.
- When speaking **to your colleagues** from another division of your company, who already knew about the existence of your team, you would use **"the team"**.

Comment: That's right. Whatever the addressee is believed to believe, if they are meeting this team for the first time, they should describe themselves as _a team_, because this makes no assumptions about the context, instead of making the addressees search for some "team" in past context. It's more helpful, if that's the goal; it's also more informative about conditions because it avoids presuppositions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "the". This can be used in cases where it's known that there's only one such team and you're explaining that it refers to you. And if it's not well known to the audience, your statement contains the implication that the team is unique; you can make this even clearer by saying "the only".

But if there's some possibility that you're not unique, you should use "a".

You also should be careful about what you consider unique about the team. If there were another team of five developers from USA, Canada, and Australia, your statement might be literally true, but I think many would consider it to be misleading -- the precise size of the team would not usually be considered an important distinguishing quality.

Answer (score 0):

You're not understanding it correctly.

Using "a team" suggests plural teams exist, whether working closely alongside or not at all closely or related but just abstractly in the whole of the universe, so all that follows "team" (i.e., "of six developers working on financial software. projects from the USA, Canada, and Australia") restrictively modifies "team" so that the receiver (i.e., the person hearing this or reading this) can narrow it down to which of the plural teams that exist you're referring to.

You could use "the," but only in certain contexts, like if the receiver confused that team with another team and you were correcting that confusion (e.g., "No, not the team of five developers working on financial software projects from China and India, the team of six developers working on financial software projects from the USA, Canada, and Australia.").

Also, you will often hear "a" used to introduce such an idea and in order to then restrict it down to a specific, whether it's a "team" or whatever. Then from that point on, with the idea having been restricted to a specific, "the" will be used, so in the case of "a team," someone might say: "We are **a** team of six developers working on financial software projects from the USA, Canada, and Australia. **The** team formed last year when... **The** team is currently planning..."